# How avoide to fetch duplicate values in one coloumn

Tags: php, mysql

```
Coloumn1
A
B
C
A
```

I want to duplicate value "A" show in Coloumn2 and Coloumn2 duplicate values shows next 3rd Column3 and so on....

Comment: Sorry friend, you're really going to have to expand the information on this one

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Currently, your question is very unclear and confusing. Remember that we know _nothing_ about your code or what you're trying to do. You need to help us to be able to help you.